# Read stdout of spawned process that is waiting for input

Tags: javascript, node.js, spawn

I have a Swift program that logs info to the `stdout` while waiting for a `\n` (that terminates the execution). It requests the input immediately after start running and logs info 1~2 seconds after:

```
fetchAndLogDataInBackground(); // will print some data in ~1 sec

readLine();
```

I'm `spawn`ing/`execFile`ing it with the following:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

const process = spawn('swift/main');
process.stdout.on('data', data => console.log(data.toString()));

setTimeout(() => {
    process.stdin.write('\n');
}, 5000);
```

I was expecting to see the logs "live" since I'm using `on('data')`, but they are only being processed after the `process.stdin.write('\n');`

There's any way to get the data "live"?

PS: if I run the Swift program in terminal (`swift/main`), it works as expected.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're expecting. To me it seems like it's working as it should: your swift program doesn't print anything until it reads a line and you are saying you don't get stdout `'data'` events until you write a new line to the swift program ...

Comment: @mscdex I'm sorry! I wrote a wrong snippet as an example :( I edited the question to correct it! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have to either disable stdout buffering or manually flush stdout in Swift.

To manually flush:

```swift
fflush(__stdoutp)
```

To disable output buffering:

```swift
setbuf(__stdoutp, nil);
```